# react server side rendering how to show html in viewsource

Tags: reactjs, express, core-ui

I downloaded react coreui from https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template

react coreui everything it's work but in viewsource of browser html code does not show up.How to send html response to client in **root** div element. I think it's impact **SEO** right?

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

I'm trying to implement server side rendering with express this's my server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))//Route ReactJS

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'..', 'build', 'index.html'))
   });
```

AFAIK the code from above should send html response to div but it's not.

I have to run this command for **/build** react files

```
npm run build
```

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository did not implement react server side rendering. 
I suggest to see this repository and learn about server side rendeing .

This repo from Daniel Stern [Daniel Stern Isomorphic-react](https://github.com/danielstern/isomorphic-react)

Comment: Yes I know about renderToString but if I try to implement it has many error window is not defined or document is not defined from @coreui library

Comment: That is right. The repo you shared, is not suitable for react server side rendering. 
For example the window and document objects are not defined in server ( in node js ) so all the codes in that repo should be converted to a version which are suitable for server ( node js ) also.